# Post with Javascript causing null session

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have legacy ASP.NET application where we post from one ASP.NET page to another with custom post javascript. First page is storing some value session. and once post to another page it is tryting to read from session but it is failing to read.  Getting null value.  This code is working fine locally and production, but not working on non-prod servers.  Reading/writing to session works fine for other application pages in all local/qa/prod.  Not able to narrow down the issue.

Note: There was no code change, same code is working fine in prod and was working with QA as well but this error started recently.

**Edit**:
I tried to replicate issue same and it is reproducing only when copy the url of erroring out page in another browser Instance where it creates new session, hence new session doesn't have value it gives same error.

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting? Is it a NullReference?

Comment: In IE it is just showing blank page, while in chrome "Page cannot be displayed because client took too long to complete its request and server closed the connection. It is showing "408 request timeout" in developer tool.

Comment: A new browser creates a new, different session, so it will not be available. You need to save info to application or somewhere else.